# Correct way to invoke protocol buffer serialization with Nancy?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, nancy

I'm using an embedded Nancy webserver and I've used Nu-Get to install the proper plugins for the built in protocol buffer serialization (Nancy.Serialization.ProtoBuf and protobuf-net).

However, the mere presence of these packages doesn't seem to be enabling protocol buffers for me. I'm sending a request with an Accepts header of application/x-protobuf. Using the Nancy diagnostic page (built-in) I can trace my request and see:

```
response Headers

status Code
    406
log
    New Request Started
    [DefaultResponseNegotiator] Processing as negotiation
    [DefaultResponseNegotiator] Original accept header: application/x-protobuf;q=1
    [DefaultResponseNegotiator] Coerced accept header: application/x-protobuf
    [DefaultResponseNegotiator] Acceptable media ranges: */*
    [DefaultResponseNegotiator] Unable to negotiate response - no headers compatible
```

So it appears as though it can't handle protocol buffers. When I check the main page of the Diagnostics site:

```
response Processors
    Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.JsonProcessor
    Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.ResponseProcessor
    Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.ViewProcessor
    Nancy.Responses.Negotiation.XmlProcessor
```

It appears as though only the default response processors are there. Protobuf isn't listed.

Any pointers on how I can get the plugin to register with Nancy?